# Draw height of ImageView before loading from URL

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, imageview, picasso

I'm receiving an image from an API/Firebase storage and loading the URL into an image view using coil/glide/picasso. The height of the imageview is set to wrap content so once it is loaded it expands, how can I draw this height before loading like other apps do ( Ex: Reddit, FB, Instagram)

Do I upload the image bitmap height width values when storing the image and this could help me?

Attached video: https://streamable.com/nf4rk0

Answer (score 0):

With picasso, I would try something like this:

```
Picasso  
    .with(context)
    .load(/*The Image*/)
    .resize(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
    .into(imageViewResize);
```

This link gives a few more examples which may help you:
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit

Comment: This would be setting a fixed height&width to the image view and resizing it to the value you specified. I don't want to do this

Comment: you're not trying to scale it to a specific size? So the image can fit in a certain view

Comment: I want to avoid this https://streamable.com/nf4rk0 
 without losing quality

Answer (score 0):

### from what i get you need to set something like this

[image: place holder image]

this special effect can be done via multiple libraries
[Like this](https://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/)

but if you need to do just the height with a grey background, you can use any placeholder image and set it as a placeholder with your desired height
it can be done also by **picasso**

Comment: Not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: oh sorry for that